# JCF of a matrix using a Jordan Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

there is an unproved proposition in my lecture notes which states:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over $K$ that admits a Jordan basis. If $P$ is the matrix having a Jordan basis as columns, then $P^{-1}AP$ is the JCF of $A$.

First off I am not sure what is meant by $A$ admits a Jordan Basis. I assumed it means that the linear map that A represents admits a Jordan basis. But then I can't convince myself that this proposition is true.
Please help!

Comment: it's a theorem refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: a Jordan basis is  a basis such that, in that basis, the matrix A assumes the JCF